# Fourier Transform of Alternating Periodic Rectangular Pulse

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier, periodic, pulse

[image]I'm having trouble determining Fourier transform of signal. I have 2 ideas on how to solve this problem. 
Given the signal is periodic I could use formula for Fourier transform of periodic signals:

$$X(j\omega) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} C_k \cdot 2\pi \delta(\omega-k\omega_{0})$$
where $\omega_0 = \frac{2 \pi}{4T}$.

Also, I could make signal $g(t)$ non periodic rectangular signal, and $h(t)$ alternating pulse train, and then $g(t)*h(t)$ should give me signal I needed.
Although I have some ideas I'm stuck solving this problem. Please help. Thanks

[image: My try]
[image: My other try]

[image: Try]

Comment: Hi! Welcome. Not quite sure what an "alternating periodic rectangular pulse" is, specifically. Can you add a formula, and/or a drawing?

Comment: Hey, i had some trouble posting photo, but I managed to do it. Take a look please

Comment: appears to me that you want the Fourier Series.  (the Fourier Transform will be a collection of impulses in the frequency domain.)

Comment: I need spectrum of signal x(t) showed on picture above. So, I'm looking for analytical form of Fourier transform of signal x(t).

Comment: what you need to know are the Fourier series coefficients, $C_k$.  from those you have your analytic expression.

Comment: True, but I'm having hard time determining them. If you could work the math out and post photo i would appriciate

Comment: again, you should edit your question to express $x(t)$ as a Fourier series with complex coefficients $C_k$.  then use the standard result from Fourier series that gives you the coefficients.

Comment: I got this as a part of an exam task, and it said using Fourier transform determine spectrum of a signal.

Comment: but it's a periodic signal, with finite power and infinite energy.  the Fourier Transform is essentially meant to be applied to non-periodic signals with finite energy.  but with a mathematical slight-of-hand, the Fourier Transform applied to a sinusoid can meaningfully be shown to be a pair of dirac delta functions in the frequency domian.  a general periodic function would have more dirac deltas ***as you have indicated in your question***.  ALL you need to do is determine the Fourier series coefficients $C_k$ and you have your answer.

Comment: Ok, I will post my results in few minutes. Please take a look and help me understand

Comment: just to be clear (i don't wanna add this to your question), the Fourier Transform (using angular frequency, $\omega$):

$$ X(j\omega) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\big\{ x(t) \big\} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j \omega t} \mathrm{d}t$$

and the Fourier series

$$  x(t) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} C_k e^{j k \omega_0 t} $$

where

$$ C_k = \frac{\omega_0}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+2 \pi/\omega_0} x(t) e^{-j k \omega_0 t}  \mathrm{d}t $$ for any real $t_0$.

Comment: I posted my try, take a look

Comment: So 2 of my methods give kinda different result in terms of sinc function. In first method, there is sinc(k*pi/4) while in other there is sinc(wT/2)

Comment: remember $$\omega_0=\frac{2\pi}{4T}$$  your period of repetition is $4T$.  (actually, it looks like you're doing that correctly.)  and in your Fourier series summation, you are including the even $k$ terms even though we know they are zero (your computation of $C_k$ was correct).  so, to get just the odds, substitute $k=2n+1$ and sum over all integer $n$.  that will make sure you're only adding up the odd terms.

Comment: Can you take a look at all my solutions and explain why they don't match up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma:**

for $x_{1}(t)$ fourier coefficient is given by $C_{n_{1}}$ [image]

$C_{n_{1}}=\dfrac{\text{amplitude}\times \text{ON duration}}{\text{Time-period}}\times Sa\left(n\  .\omega_{0}. \frac{\text{ON duration}}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\tau}{T_{0}}\times Sa\left(n\  .\omega_{0}. \frac{{\tau}}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi n \tau}{T_{0}}\right)}{n\pi}$

where

$Sa(\lambda x)=\dfrac{\sin \lambda x}{\lambda x}$

**for your question :** $\tau=T ; T_{0}=4T$

also,

fourier coefficient of $x(t)$  is $C_{n}=C_{n_{1}}(1-e^{-jn\pi})=C_{n_{1}}[1-(-1)^n]$ (by use of linearity +time shifting as stated in  @ royi's answer)

$C_{n}=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi n }{4}\right)}{n\pi}[1-(-1)^n]$

and now you can find fourier transform by using formula of periodic function's F.T. i.e.,  $X(j\omega)$

so, your first method is correct . but your second method(using convolution) is awesome ( i haven't checked it yet though )

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.
I will give 3 points to solve it:

1. The Fourier transform is linear. Hence $ \mathcal{ F } \left\{ \alpha f \left( x \right) + \beta g \left( x \right) \right\} = \alpha \mathcal{ F } \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\} + \beta \mathcal{ F } \left\{ g \left( x \right) \right\} $.
2. Shift in time $ f \left( x - {x}_{0} \right) $ equals multiplication by $ {e}^{-j \omega {x}_{0}} $ in Fourier domain.
3. Instead of solving for the case above, think of the case you have 2 rectangular signals with twice the period with one multiplied by $ -1 $ and shifted.

In your case, just have a look on the signal of the Positive Pulses. It has a period of $ 4T $.
You have another signal. The signal of the negative pulses.
It is basically the same signal as the positive one (It also has a period of $ 4T $) yet it is shifted by $ 2T $ and as it is multiplied by $ -1 $.
So if you know the transform of the positive one, follow my above points and you have the transform of the negative one and their sum.

Comment: As I know, shift in time equals multiplication by exponential function e^(j*w*to)

Comment: You're correct and I clarified my bad choice of words. Thank You.

Comment: Still not sure how would you solve this problem. If you could work it out and take a photo it would mean a lot. I'm new to this field so I'm finding these problems difficult

Comment: Do you know the Fourier Transform of a rectangular pulse with a period of $ {T}_{0} $?

Comment: Of course, Rectangular pulse with period $T$ and amplitude $A$ is $A$$T$$sinc(\frac{wT}{2})$

Comment: Great. What if you shift it by $ \frac{T}{2} $? What if you multiply it by $ -1 $? If you have the answer for that, just add it to another vanilla one (No shift and no multiplication).

Comment: Then that is just 2 pulses. I need Fourier transform of infinite amount of those.

Comment: When I asked you about the transform I asked about the train of Pulses.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a more specific idea.

Comment: Take a look, I posted a photo up there

Comment: Any help on my try?

Comment: It seems to be correct. I didn't check it per constant, but you can do it with simulation.

Comment: Can you help with $[1-e^{-jw2T}]$

Comment: I really dont understand why I'm getting different results.